# unexpected output when trying to pre/post increment/decrement in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x = 5;
cout << ++x << x-- << --x;
cout << x << --x << ++x;

return 0;
}
```

its just a simple code to try the pre,post increment/decrement function in order to learn it but The output differs from the expected output

was expecting the output as : 664434 but unusually it turned out : 444444

Comment: you should publish the code and the outputs inside the post

Comment: And don't post images (when it can easily be avoided, as it can be here)

Comment: ok thanks to both of you i dont even know how to reply to a specific user :) , is this relevant now ? i edited it .

Comment: Invoking Undefined Behaviour here

Comment: @abutolba Use `@user`, where user is the username you want to reply to

Comment: @PaulSanders ok thank you , what else i have to do to reopen the question , i deleted the photo and dropped off the code

Comment: Your question is answered in the dup (just follow the link) - and don't write code like that!

Comment: In general, if the dup really doesn't help you, you need to edit the question to explain why the dup doesn't already answer your question and/or how your question is different, and make sure the "submit for review" checkbox is checked before you click "Save". In this case however I do believe the dup answers your question.

Comment: @WeijunZhou sry , which dup excatlly

Comment: You see the notice in your question? That is the duplicate that supposedly answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/what-are-sequence-points-and-how-do-they-relate-to-undefined-behavior